# How to use connectify to share files between 2 laptops, one running Windows 7?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, connection-sharing, connectify

I have 2 laptops one running XP and another Windows 7. Both have WiFi-card installed. I want to be able to share files between these 2 machines and then in next step also be able to share internet connection.

I have heard that Connectify on Windows 7 is a very handy and easy tool to set up a hotspot and other machines even XP,Vista can connect to this host hotspot and share files and internet connection.

I am able to search for the network (set on host) on my client machine. But how to share files? I don't see any such menu or anything.

Also after I have installed connectify on Windows 7, I am not able to connect to internet using data card. It throws error that "Error 31:A A device attached to the system is not functioning".

And on client machine, if I connect to data card, as well as connect to wireless network setup by host machine, I no longer am able to access internet, even though the data card is connected. The browser throws error: [image: browser error]

Please help.

Any other utility similar to connectify etc?

Comment: What's the WiFi card/chipset on the Windows 7 system?

Comment: how to find this?

Comment: Use [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy)

Comment: The Connectify website mentions that you need the Pro version in order to "Browse Shared folders and other services in your network".  Are you using basic?

Also, what is your internet setting in Connectify on the Win7 PC?  If you are using basic, it looks like the default setting might be "No internet sharing".

Answer (score 1):

What type of hotspot are you creating?
You should create an ad-hoc hotspot in connectify and browse shared folders in "Network".

If it doesn't work out, use a free tool called **ipmessenger**.
It will enable sending files over standard windows ad-hoc wifi. But, it wont enable browsing of shared folders.

One more option, you can probably use standard windows ad-hoc connection for file sharing and connectify for internet sharing.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution you are looking at it, but as far as your are looking for the solution that make your computer to communicate wireless look at it.
For an alternate solution you may have look at [virtual router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/).

It allows you to make your laptop behave like wireless router. Allows your client to connect to it and it can also share the internet connection too.

Very easy to setup and free!
Go for it and have a try.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember there is option in Windows 7 for creating WiFi network. In other words your laptop is turning into WiFi hotspot and then it should be easier to share files between your computers.